# How do I illustrate a somewhat simple human figure?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, education, anatomy-for-artists

I want to make similar videos like [these guys](http://thecuillincollective.co.uk/explanation-videos/portfolio/). I therefore have to draw some stickman and make them animate somehow.

My Questions:

- How to draw stickmen. No, really, how?
- What to watch out for when drawing?
- Draw on paper or draw in photoshop and print?
- If paper, which type of pen to use?
- Are there any good tutorials on this?

Thank you very much for reading :)

Note: your free to laugh :D

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "straw man"? If you are asking how to do what they did in that video, then the answer is: paper, markers, scissors.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's stickman :D

Comment: So...you're asking how to draw a stickman? :)

Comment: Yes exactly :) In terms of "i know it, i do it like this but, is there a proper way to do it" & etc ;)

Comment: There is never a "proper way" to draw anything. You can use crayons on cardboard. Ballpoint on paper. Bananas on concrete. It doesn't matter. Once it's drawn you can take a photo or scan the result and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to draw stickmen. No, really, how?
Are there any good tutorials on this?

First of all create a story board with all characters and list all the elements you will be using, such as backgrounds and objects. Next is to look up your favorite illustrator and use that as a simple guide. Like Scott said the artist is you. If you draw a body it tends to be 6 to 7 1/2 heads high.. Make a cross, draw a circle on top and have a line come off it, upside down v for legs. Once that's accomplished then make the lines to rectangles and section off so it looks like clothes. Use pencil lightly, outline with a fine to medium point sharpie and use Crayola or similar colored pencils to color them. Yes, you have Bob Ross for painting, I [learned](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tK70tHKhME) from Mark Kistler shows. Shading, marker everything, though my style comes from someone I worked for. Get inspired from other artists.

Draw on paper or draw in photoshop and print?
If paper, which type of pen to use?

They look like they used index cards. If you aren't using the originals to shoot the video then use a grainy recycled paper. Try not to use expensive coated or laser printer paper, you can avoid glare that way, whether you shoot or scan. Plus coated is really slick and prone to smudges.

What to watch out for when drawing?

Draw what you see. Everything is a shape. Think about when you leave someone a message. You write the word "call", it doesn't look like "F-R-H-2". The video, and I'm serious, is what got me into pencil and ink and after watching a few you'll realized he's the Bob Ross to cartoons. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will consider this valuable informations

Comment: No sweat, I take it for granted at times. Glad that helped.